# Laravel - Trying to get property of non-object on Collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I'm trying to pass some SEO Values to a blade view.

My Blade view is as follows :

```
@if(!empty($page_data))
        <?php $page_data = $page_data[0]; ?>
        <title>{{ $page_data->page_seo_title }}</title>
        <meta name="description" content="{{ $page_data->page_seo_desc }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="page_id" class="page_id" value="{{ $page_data->page_id }}">
@endif
```

When I pass the following collection the view, I get the **error :**

> Trying to get property of non-object

My collection looks as follows :

```
Collection {#286 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "page_seo_title" => "SEO Title"
      "page_seo_desc" => "SEO Desc"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I am building the collection, Like so :

```
// Set Page Data
            $page_data  = collect(
                [
                    [
                        'page_seo_title' => 'SEO Title',
                        'page_seo_desc' => 'SEO Desc'
                    ]
                ]
            );
```

Do I need to define something else within the collection so that it gets' picked up?

It's worth pointing out that the page_data works on pages that have an Eloquent Query running on them, So that's not an issue. Its' just these dynamic pages, That I need to set. So ideally I don't need to change the blade / view logic. Just the collection / controller logic.

Comment: $page_data  = collect(
                [
                    
                        'page_seo_title' => 'SEO Title',
                        'page_seo_desc' => 'SEO Desc'
                    
                ]
            ); or you need to $page_data[0]->page_seo_title in blade

Comment: Hi @iCoders this in turn returns an error : Undefined offset: 0 :/

Comment: then try to convert collection to array like  $page_data->toArray(); then print it check how data will come

Comment: Use `$page_data['page_seo_title']` rather than `$page_data->page_seo_title`

Comment: @ArminSam Yes, but this in turn won't work when I return an Eloquent collection to the view. As that's returning objects

Comment: Then maybe `$page_data` is an empty collection in the first place. You cannot use `empty()` on collection objects, cause they always return false. Change the line with `@if(!empty($page_data))` into `@if(!$page_data->isEmpty())` and see whether the error happens again?

Answer (score 0):

i have updated small example based on your code and its tested.try once

```
 $page_data  = collect(
                        [
                            [
                                'page_seo_title' => 'SEO Title',
                                'page_seo_desc' => 'SEO Desc'
                            ]
                        ]
                    );

//here it will print all data 
                    print_r($page_data->toArray());

                    $data=$page_data->toArray();

// here it will print particular data
                echo    $data[0]['page_seo_title'];
```

**Updated**

in your controller

```
$data=$page_data->toArray();

        return view('viewname',['data',$data];
```

in your blade

```
@if(!empty($data))
    <?php $new_data = $data[0]; ?>
    <title>{{ $new_data['page_seo_title'] }}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="{{ $new_data['page_seo_desc'] }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="page_id" class="page_id" value="{{ $new_data['page_id'] }}">
```

Comment: Unfortunatley, No further with that... 

Same Error : Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Could I maybe try some logic in the blade - Check for an object, If not check for an element?

Comment: And if you pass `$page_data->first()` in your controller, you don't need the `<?php` tags in your blade view

Answer (score 0):

There is no page_id property in you collection but you access it in your blade view. 
please check your that line

```
<input type="hidden" name="page_id" class="page_id" value="{{ $page_data->page_id }}">
```

there you access page_id but your collection doesn't contain a propery with page_id.